Evaluating complex integration $\int_k^{\infty } \text{csch}(z) \exp (-z) \, dz$
I am trying to evaluate the complex definite integration below, where $k$ is a complex number and the integration path is assumed to be the line joining $k$ and ${\infty }$:
$$\int_k^{\infty } \text{csch}(z) \exp (-z) \, dz$$
I could evaluate the indefinite integral:
$$\text{indef} = \int \text{csch}(z) \exp (-z) \, dz = 2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(1-2 e^{2 z}\right)$$
I wish to have the answer for the definite integration to be in terms of the principal branch of $\tanh ^{-1}$.
At $z = {\infty }$, the limit of $\text{indef}$ is $i \pi$, and applying a branch cut correction of $-2*i*\pi$, for certain values of $k$, the definite integral can be written as:
$$\text{def} = -i \pi -2 \tanh ^{-1}(1-2 \exp (2 k))$$
However this expression should be valid only when we do not encounter any other branch cuts of $\tanh ^{-1}$ while going from $k$ and $ {\infty }$.
For example, the expression looks correct for $k = 2+i$, but incorrect for $k = 2+2*i$.
Can someone help me to determine the condition on $k$ for which the expression is valid? I tried using CAS but not getting a reliable answer.

$\int_k^\infty  {{\mathop{\rm csch}\nolimits} (z){\rm e}^{ - z} {\rm d}z}  =  - \log (1 - {\rm e}^{ - 2k} )$ and the RHS has logarithmic branch points at integer multiples of $\pi\mathrm{i}$.

@Gary, this does look correct numerically. Could you kindly explain how you arrived at this? maybe post as an answer?

Assume that $k>0$. You can very that the derivative of the RHS is $-\operatorname{csch}(k)\mathrm{e}^{-k}$. The constant of integration is $0$ since both sides tend to zero as $k\to+\infty$. The restriction on $k$ is then removed by analytic continuation.
